# C combining date and time value

Tags: c, date, time

I have my codes working where I got separate date and time columns. I would like to add one more column which have both date and time in. For the existing codes this how I did

```
sprintf(all,'%02d:%02d:%02d.%06u%03u',CURDATE(),s / 3600, (s % 3600) / 60, s % 60, usec, nsec)
```

I tried this does not work

```
sprintf(all,'%02d:%02d:%02d.%06u%03u',CURDATE(),'CURDATE() %02d:%02d:%02d.%06u%03u',s / 3600, (s % 3600) / 60, s % 60, usec, nsec,s / 3600, (s % 3600) / 60, s % 60, usec, nsec)
```

I need the space between the curdate and time ?

Comment: `CURDATE` does not exist in the standard C language. It is peculiar to your programming environment, or a definition in your project. **String literals are delimited by double quotes in C.** (Knowing things like that constitutes minimal understanding).

Comment: @Kaz yes curdate is part of mysql support. So what is best suggestion in your case for C to use curdate or something else?

Comment: The best suggestion is to go through C tutorials and books to learn things how to code in C; meanwhile, give the task to someone who has already done that.

Comment: Re-write your question with code that compiles from your "I have my codes working where I got separate date and time columns".  It is obvious that your posted _working code_ is not valid.  Then show what you have then tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have not added format specifier for the added column.

Comment: What to do and where exactly to add? Any idea ?

Comment: @user2711681: See `man 2 printf`.

Comment: @I have tried but its giving me this error too many argument for format and also format expect type inta but argument has 16 has type achar *a